# Why time limit is exceeding in SPOJ prime generator code?

Tags: c++

```
enter code here
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,arr[100],a,b;
    bool isPrime = true;
    cin>>t;
    while(t!=0)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
       {
            for(int j=2; j <= i/2; ++j)
            {
                if(i%j == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            if(isPrime)
                cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen many solved codes which are using  STL but why this code is not ok please suggest how can I improve.

Comment: I revoked my earlier comment. My new comment is: Do **not** learn programming this way. It'll lead you astray. Follow up question: Do you know what the "inner loop" is in your program?

Comment: This solution scales exponentially. I would suggest that you take a look at the algorithm called `Sieve of Eratosthenes`  to solve this question on SPOJ

Comment: Rishi's right, but perhaps you can get a pass by making two trivial changes here: 1) Output "2" up front and then make `i` skip all other even numbers, and 2) break out of the inner loop once `j` squared is greater than `i`.